# Why is Mathjax creating duplicates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mathjax

I'm using MathJax to render MathML in my application.  I include the following code to ensure that MathML is typeset:

```
$rootScope.$watch(function() {
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
    return true;
});
```

The issue is that when I navigate away and then return to the MathML, it's rendered twice.  If I repeat this step, it renders 3 times and so on.  Does anyone understand what's going on here?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem? Because right now, all I (or anyone else) can say is that either there's a bug in MathJax or Angular or you're doing something wrong with the way you're using them. Which I'm sure you could figure out on your own already anyway.

Comment: Watch functions are invoked two or more times every digest cycle. I understand what is going on. I don't understand what you are trying to do. Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope `$watch` Performance Considerations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-watch-performance-considerations).

Answer (score 0):

The project I'm working on was originally coded by someone else.  It's difficult to replicate the issue in a simple way, however I have a general answer for this problem which did end up solving the issue.

In this case I needed to avoid using Element.innerHTML or jquery's .html() method with MathML.  I can't explain exactly why this caused the issue, but in my particular case it did.